# ArcMap calculate area automatically after edit

Tags: arcmap, shape-area

Is there any way to calculate area automatically when I edit a polygon? I mean, is there any function there I can use on area field and update itself when I finish editing?

Answer (score 3):

If you keep your data in a file geodatabase the area in the SHAPE_Area field is automatically updated/calculated:

[image]

Comment: is there any way to see the area as square kilometers this way?

Comment: @AliDağ just change the field display properties : as number format choose rate with a factor of 1000000 and add a km² suffix